# R: uploading (.csv) file to ftp server

Tags: r, csv, ftp, rcurl

does anyone of you have an idea of how to upload an R file (saved in the R environment) onto an FTP server?

It would be perfect to export the file directly as **.csv** or **.json** file, so I already tried some solutions like:

```
write.csv2(my.data, file = url("ftp://user:password@ftpserver.net/mydata.csv"))
```

or

```
write_json(my.data, path = url("ftp://user:password@ftpserver.net/folder/mydata.csv"))
```

but, unfortunately, in both cases R gives me the error:

```
"can only open URLs for reading"
```

which is kind of sad, but makes sense anyway.

Ok, after that I tried to work with the RCurl library - like this:

```
library("RCurl")
userpwd <- "user:password"
ftpUpload(I(my.data), "ftp://ftpserver.net/folder/mydata.csv", userpwd=userpwd, asText = T)
```

which doesn't work properly as well. Somehow this command brings R to a "fatal error" so that my session gets terminated - and oddly enough an empty mydata.csv file gets uploaded onto the FTP server.

To be honest, I have no clue of how to deal with that.

Does anyone of you have a smart idea? 
Would a temp file bring a solution? My ideal is, to avoid storing data locally on my laptop but instead saving (and exporting it) directly onto the ftp server.

Many, many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried writing it to a `tempfile` and then uploading that?

Comment: I never thought to try R's URL mechanism for *up*loading, just *down*loading. (And frankly, the use of `ftp://` by itself is bothersome with its ineffective "security" ...) Does the file upload work if you save to a local file and attempt it externally to R? (At least for testing.)

Comment: (Sorry, I edited out the `json` tag before realizing its possible relevance. I don't currently have a "rollback" option, you should be able to do the rollback yourself. Sorry for the edit-noise.)